# Conditional formatting based on text of cell on another tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

thank you in advance for your help.
I would like to conditional format Sheet1C3 depending if Sheet2C3 contains specific text.
IF cell contains text "Closed", format cell colour grey. IF contains text "Active", format cell colour green. I would like this to work for cells C3:W174, corresponding cells Sheet1/ Sheet2.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

green:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!C3:C")="Active"
```

grey:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!C3:C")="Closed"
```

[image: 0]